# select first 10 rows and then select 5 random row of them

Tags: sql, select

i want to select first 10 rows then select 5 random rows of them.

Comment: That's nice. Do you have any more context to your question?

Comment: So you want to select 5 random rows of first 10 rows? :)

Comment: Which SQL ? MySQL, T-SQL or Oracle based ??

Comment: "first 10 rows" -> need to be ordered somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have to define "first 10" and it's "something" in this snippet. This is for SQL Server 2000+

```
select top 5 
    * 
from 
    (
    select top 10 * from <table>
    order by something --got to have soemthing here to define "first 10"
    ) as a
order by 
    newid()
```

Edit:

Why you need ORDER BY in the derived table

```
-- large row, same result with and without index/PK
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar int /*PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (bar)*/, eejit char(8000))

--create rows with value 1-10 + some others
INSERT #foo (bar) VALUES (1)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (10)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (20)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (2)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (5)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (45)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (99)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (3)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (9)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (7)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (6)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (4)
INSERT #foo (bar)  VALUES (8)

--create logical fragmentation
DELETE #foo WHERE bar IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
INSERT #foo (bar) VALUES (1)
INSERT #foo (bar) VALUES (3)
INSERT #foo (bar) VALUES (5)
INSERT #foo (bar) VALUES (7)
INSERT #foo (bar) VALUES (9)

-- run this a few times, you will see values > 10
-- "first 10" surely means values between 1 and 10?
select top 5 
    * 
from 
    (
    select top 10 * from #foo
    ) as a
order by 
    newid()

-- always <= 10 because of ORDER BY
select top 5 
    * 
from 
    (
    select top 10 * from #foo
    order by bar --got to have soemthing here to define "first 10"
    ) as a
order by 
    newid()
```

Comment: No with SQL-Server you do not need order by something

Comment: Odd. For me, on SQL-Server 2008, this works fine without the "something" -- see bernd_k's answer. (Aaaand a cross-reply. Oh well. :-) )

Comment: @bernd_k: yes you do. Otherwise TOP is meaningless. There is **no** implicit ordering and "first 10" has to first according to some criteria

Comment: @gbn: maybe, but it compiles and runs and gives reasonable results.

Comment: @Christian Severin: TOP 10 what? I didn't say "fail": I said it won't answer question

Comment: mine was without the "as a" !! thanks anyway : select top 5 
    * 
from 
    (
    select top 10 * from <table>
    order by something --got to have soemthing here to define "first 10"
    ) 
order by 
    newid()

Comment: @Christian Severin, @bernd_k: see my sample script please for why TOP is meaningless without ORDER BY

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from 
    (select * from table order by id limit 10) as rows  order by rand() limit 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to do but this may help (in MySQL):

```
 SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

use [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) and [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) to achieve your desired goal.

Comment: RAND in SQL Server (clarified by OP) would give RAND the same for all rows and does nt have LIMIT

Comment: @gbn, by the time OP clarified, I had already answered.